# Locality-sensitive hashing - Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, locality-sensitive-hash, minhash

is there any plugin allowing LSH on Elasticsearch? If yes, could you point me to the location and tell me a little how to use it?
Thanks

Edit:
I found out that ES uses MinHash plugin. How could I compare documents to one another with this? What would be a good setting to find duplicates?

Answer (score 6):

1. There is a [Elasticsearch MinHash Plugin](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-minhash). You can use it to extract minhash value every time you index a document and query the document by minhash later.

   1. Install MinHash plugin:

      ```
      $ $ES_HOME/bin/plugin install org.codelibs/elasticsearch-minhash/2.3.1
      ```
   2. Add a minhash analyzer when creating your index:

      ```
      $ curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/my_index' -d '{
        "index":{
          "analysis":{
            "analyzer":{
              "minhash_analyzer":{
                "type":"custom",
                "tokenizer":"standard",
                "filter":["minhash"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }'
      ```
   3. Put `minhash_value` field into an index mapping:

      ```
      $ curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_mapping" -d '{
        "my_type":{
          "properties":{
            "message":{
              "type":"string",
              "copy_to":"minhash_value"
            },
            "minhash_value":{
              "type":"minhash",
              "minhash_analyzer":"minhash_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }'
      ```
   4. The minhash value is calculated automatically when adding document to the index you have created with minhash analyzer.
   5. a. [Use More like this query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) can be used to do "like" search on the `minhash_value` field:

      ```
      GET /_search
      {
          "query": {
              "more_like_this" : {
                  "fields" : ["minhash_value"],
                  "like" : "KV5rsUfZpcZdVojpG8mHLA==",
                  "min_term_freq" : 1,
                  "max_query_terms" : 12
              }
          }
      }
      ```

      b. You can also use [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) but it accepts the query to differ from the result by `2` (maximum).

      ```
      GET /_search
      {
          "query": {
             "fuzzy" : { "minhash_value" : "KV5rsUfZpcZdVojpG8mHLA==" }
          }
      }
      ```

      You can find more about the fuzzy query [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness).
2. Or you can create the hash value outside of elasicsearch (write a code to extract hash value) and everytime you index a document you can run the code and attach the hash value to the document you are indexing. And later search with the hash value using [More Like This query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) or [Fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) as described above.
3. Last but not least, you can write elasticsearch plugin yourself as above (which suits you hashing algorithm) and do the same step above.

Comment: Can only use fuzzy queries on keyword and text fields - not on [minhash_value] which is of type [minhash]

Comment: Even `more_like_this` queries do not work, they only support `text` and `keyword` fields. Any workaround for this?

Comment: is there still no solution for this somehow?

Comment: there is a "copy_bits_to" operator, but I can't show me that field?

Comment: how to create hash value outside of elasticsearch?